# Estimation in case of data dependent noise

Tags: estimation, linear-model, heteroscedasticity, linear, estimators

I am trying to estimate $a$ and $b$ in the below linear model 
$$y = ax + b + \epsilon$$

where $x \in R^n$ and $y \in R^n$ are given, and $\epsilon$ depends on the parameters and the $x$. Also, it is given that each element of $\epsilon$ is independent, is from an unknown distribution and given $x$, the mean is 0. I don't know what is the best way to estimate $a$ and $b$ given $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Do you know more about the dependence structure?

Comment: @shadowtalker No, can you please provide a pointer for it?

Comment: I am asking if you can provide us with more information on the nature of the dependence

Comment: @shadowtalker Only this much information is given.